# Simple Math with tables PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `$row['seuil_pil']` that contains only numbers. And i want to increse these numbers by a certain amount but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
$roof=0.12;      

$seuil_haut= array_product(($row['seuil_pil']*$roof) + $row['seuil_pil']);
```

**OR**

```
$seuil_haut= array(($row['seuil_pil']*$roof) + $row['seuil_pil']);
```

**OR**

```
$seuil_haut= ($row['seuil_pil']*$roof) + $row['seuil_pil'];
```

**OR**

```
foreach ($row['seuil_pil'] as $seuil_haut[])
{
    $seuil_haut[] = ($roof * $row['seuil_pil'] + $row['seuil_pil'] ); 
}
```

Comment: Did you think of using a `foreach` loop for this?

Comment: yes, but i don't think i got it right

Comment: Is it a one-dimensional array? How does the content of `$row['seuil_pil']` looks like?

Comment: yes, and it has only positive numers

Comment: can you vardump $row

Comment: What do you mean by "increase"? Addition?

Comment: for example my table has 90 and 81. In the end i need them to be 12% higher

Comment: @elianero I edited my post. Could you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for`-loop:

```
$roof = 0.12;

$row['seuil_pil'] = array(4,1,3);

for($i = 0; $i < count($row['seuil_pil']); $i++) {
    $row['seuil_pil'][$i] *= (1 + $roof);
} 

var_dump($row['seuil_pil']);

//results in:
//array(3) { [0]=> float(4.48) [1]=> float(1.12) [2]=> float(3.36) }
```

Comment: @downvoter: I edited my post. I wrongly used `$row['seuil_pil']` instead of `$entry`

Comment: This will still not work because you're not using a reference. The result of the calculation is not used anywhere.

Comment: My answer will work. Test it and test yours. Then downvote my answer if I'm wrong or delete yours if I'm right.

Comment: @MadDog You're right. I was not aware of the reference topic. I changed it to a `for` loop. I upvoted your answer. But you could also shorten your mathematical operation with `*=` as i've done

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it's possible, but IMO my version is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply operations to the array that you're iterating over, you must use `foreach` with a reference:

```
foreach ($row['seuil_pil'] as &$cell) {
    $cell = $cell * $roof + $cell;
}
```